# Problem with Regex.replace function in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

I am formatting file which is downloaded from internet  and I encountered ... , ...... So I want to replace these multiple dots with single dot. 
String.Replace is not going work here and I am not good with regular expressions So what is the solution..?

Thank you

Comment: So in your input string of **... , ....** you'd want **. , .** to be the result?

Comment: yes I want to replace multiple dots with single dot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is you could use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx):

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\.+", ".");
```

Note that you *don't* have to escape the `.` in the replacement pattern - *only* [substitution patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) are recognised within the replacement pattern.

Comment: yeh.. The above code works. But why did you used "@" here...?

Comment: @AjitHegde: It's a case of a [string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). When you need (or want) to use escaped characters in a string and not escape the string itself (i.e., regex, file paths, etc.) you use these for readability/ease of use.

Comment: The "@" causes the C# compiler to treat the '\' as a normal character instead as an escape character

Comment: I used it with files but I didnt know It also works with regular expressions.. Thanks for the information

Comment: @Brad: I think you mean a *verbatim string literal*. Just "foo" is a *regular string literal*.

Comment: @Ajit: The compiler doesn't know or care how the string is used. It's just trying to work out which characters to put in the string.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Indeed, I was just citing the page title. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
myFileContents = Regex.Replace(myFileContents, @"\.+", ".");
```

<sup>[[Reference]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx)</sup>

In the future, please reference this site as a source of help, not code. That is to say, provide what you've tried, what you're having problem(s) with, and how it's not working as you've anticipated--not "code this for me".